# conditional .set method for preparedstatement recursively

Tags: java, recursion, prepared-statement

i have a list of columns to check for null and insert them to db.
i know it is simple if/else.

```
    if (lvl1.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) {
        stmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    } else {
        stmt.setString(2, lvl1);
    }
```

but for at least 10 columns to write this, i hope there is more easier simpler one-line code to do this for each column.

is there any recursive method that would make this simpler? 
is there any one-line code that could determine column value and assign the `.set` method whether `.setNull()` or `.setString()` ?
maybe somethin like `lvl1.setCheckNull(String)` means that it checks for null if null then `.setNull()` not then `.setString()`.

Comment: Update the Question. Don't post on comments .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write your own method like

```
public void setString(PreparedStatement ps, int parameterIndex, String str) throws SQLException
{
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL"))
        ps.setNull(parameterIndex, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    else
        ps.setString(parameterIndex, str);
}
```

and then use it like

```
setString(preparedStatement, 2, stringToCheck);
setString(preparedStatement, 3, string2ToCheck);
```

and so on, for your 10 columns.